# Insert UTC timestamp (millis) into Oracle timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is there a way how to **directly** convert value in milliseconds (e.g. 1480515430991) to Oracle TIMESTAMP(6) column? Like some pattern I'm missing for the TO_TIMESTAMP or TO_DATE functions?

All I could find so far are some calculations with intervals and **to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')** or other crazy "manual" calculations.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thanks guys. I didn't ask how to do the conversion though. I asked if there is a direct (native, more straightforward) way to achieve it and avoid these calculations for a given input. I am just a curious person and there are many undocumented features out there (Oracle not excluded). I guess NO is my answer then.

Comment: What is meant by 0 milliseconds? Is that the start of the day? Week? Some other date?

Comment: The epoch. It's the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Comment: Timestamp is fractional seconds, not milliseconds. Here you can find the documentation of 11g's `to_timestamp` function https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm#OLADM696

Comment: @Kousalik no, default is in seconds.

Comment: You are correct: there is no Oracle function that takes Unix time as an argument and outputs an Oracle date or timestamp. The only way is to use manual calculations. Not sure why you think the calculations are "crazy" - ANY function that would do the conversion for you would use the same calculations. Perhaps what is "crazy" is that we all have to repeat the same calculations instead of Oracle providing the facility, but that is not a characteristic of the calculations themselves. Complain to Oracle!

Comment: I named it crazy because measuring time in millis since the epoch is a common thing on many other platforms. These calculations are very common on the internet though. I like not to stick to some presumptions and copy paste thre first solution just because it worked for someone somewhere. I like looking for better solutions if I don't feel comfortable with the options I know. NO is also an answer (very often a good one). Cheers.

Comment: I landed here because I had exactly the same question. I have timestamps from perl mtime that are epoch seconds. It would've been nice if I could've just dropped those numbers into oracle. It is a teensy bit crazy that oracle couldn't provide the simple conversion necessary - still, at least I now know.

Answer (score 2):

Correct function, i.e. include time zone consideration and milliseconds would be this one (using literals):

```
create or replace function epoch2timestamp(epoch number) return timestamp as
begin
return (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + epoch/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get timestamp from epoch.:

```
select to_timestamp('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * epoch from dual;
```

So in insert please insert `to_timestamp('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * epoch` instead of epoch. You can also create function for that:

```
create or replace function epoch2timestamp(epoch number) return timestamp as
begin
return to_timestamp('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * epoch;
end;
/
```

And then operate on function. These are not "crazy manual calculations" just a legal way of conversion.

Comment: And as I said in the question, this is what I was able to figure on my own.

Comment: @Kousalik And this is answer to your question. It is direct conversion which you need. Donvoting won't give you better answers but can discourage others to help you.

Comment: Note, this function will return result as **UTC** value, not your local time. You have go consider time zone and convert it, if required.

Comment: Well your function is "crazy" in regards to: Create a TIMESTAMP, implicit cast to DATE, and again implicit cast to TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to express the unix time, the time since epoch, you need seconds, not milliseconds. See [Unixtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Oracle's datatype `TIMESTAMP` is in fractional seconds, as you can read in the Oracle documentation. [Link zu 11g documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021)

> Year, month, and day values of date, as well as hour, minute, and second values of time, where fractional_seconds_precision is the number of digits in the fractional part of the SECOND datetime field. Accepted values of fractional_seconds_precision are 0 to 9.

And to answer your question: there is a `TO_TIMESTAMP` function. See [11g documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm#OLADM696)

> The TO_TIMESTAMP function converts text data to a value of TIMESTAMP data type.

You can use it like this

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/11/30 15:53:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

and would get '30-NOV-16 15.53.18.000000000 AM'

---

If, for some reason, you really need to display the seconds sind epoch, you can use the noncrazy calculation

```
select (SYSDATE - to_date('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) * 24 * 60 * 60 from dual;
```

Comment: This is only correct if your database server runs on UTC time zone.